# Block (nullroute?) an IPv6 hostname using /etc/hosts

Tags: debian, ipv6, hosts, dnsmasq, hosts-file

I'm trying to prevent my web browser from communicating with certain hosts (mostly ads and tracking). I have a list of such hosts in my `/etc/hosts` file.

For IPv4 I can do:

```
255.255.255.255 example.com
```

How can I do that with IPv6?
The following two do not seem to work:

```
::1     example.com
ff02::2 example.com
```

This is for `dnsmasq` on a Debian machine. Please assist

**UPD** Please also advise what's an easy way to check the results - something similar to nslookup on Windows. Tried `dig -6 example.com` but it hangs and then throws an error.

```
# dig example.com -6

; <<>> DiG <<>> example.com -6
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: Exactly what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm trying to prevent my web browser from communicating with certain hosts.

Comment: Why bother with IPv6 specifically? If your browser is using names to look up the hosts, then it doesn't care whether it gets an IPv4 or IPv6 address back. If it's already doing IPv6 then it's already found an address and nothing you can put in /etc/hosts will change that.

Comment: wow@wurtel. You *really* missed the point of an ad-blocking hosts file!

Answer (score 1):

To override both IPv6 and IPv4 name lookups, you need both in `/etc/hosts`.  I just tried using `::1 example.com` in `/etc/hosts` and it did work as expected.

You may have `ping6` and `traceroute6` variants installed -- you should use those for testing. `ping` and `traceroute` tend to be IPv4-only, though the Windows version of `ping` does have a `-6` parameter for IPv6 mode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The line that worked for me back then is `ff02::2 example.com`

Comment: Just a note that nowdays GNU/Linux version of `ping` also have `-4`/`-6` (although there is also *still* separate `ping6` which basically does the same thing as `ping -6`)

Answer (score 0):

adding both IPv4 and IPv6 entries to `/etc/hosts` will block both.

```
 ::1       example.com
 127.0.0.1 example.com
```

Note that you **cannot use** `dig`, `host`, `nslookup` etc. to check such `/etc/hosts` blackhole - they will all connect directly to DNS servers, bypassing `/etc/hosts` (you can use other values if you run local web server but don't want that behavior, of course).

you can check with:

```
telnet -4 example.com 80
telnet -6 example.com 80
telnet example.com 80
```

or opening browser to `http://example.com/`, etc. Note that if you *do run web server at your own machine*, it will get connections for `127.0.0.1` and `::1` (which you can use creatively if you want to log such requests, or show default content etc).

Comment: Most browsers look for IPv6 first, and if it resolves, use it and never look up IPv4 addresses. So no. You're wrong.

Comment: On macOS 11.0.1, I added `255.255.255.255 name.org` for a name that also resolves to an IPv6 address. When using ping6 or Firefox for `name.org`, the name resolves to the public IPv6 address.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs things changed a lot since original answer in 2014, so I've updated answer now. Nowdays browsers will use IPv4 if IPv6 fails or is slower (and vice versa) due to RFC6555 (HappyEyeballs), and even other tools might have different IPv4/IPv6 priorities depending on `/etc/gai.conf` etc.